# how to perform right join in two pandas data frames on common column basis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to merge two data frames on common column value basis.
`df1` is

```
       DDAY MM  YYYY    new
0        8  1   1975    8
1        7  1   1975    7
2       14  1   1975    14
3        4  1   1975    4
4       13  1   1975    13
... ... ... ... ...     ...
5270    28  12  2018   362
5271     2  12  2018   336
5272     8  12  2018   342
5273    20  12  2018   354
5274     7  12  2018   341
```

with dimension `2640 rows × 4 columns`
while `df3`is

```
        YYYY    DOY HR    By     Bz     Nsw  Vsw
1       1975    1   0   -2.5     1.1    4.2  498.
2       1975    2   0   -1.7     0.2    6.2  371.
3       1975    3   0    1.0     0.4   16.7  384.
4       1975    4   0   999.9   999.9   7.5  639.
5       1975    5   0   999.9   999.9   3.1  702.
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ....    ....  ...
16067   2018    361 0    -0.8     0.8  13.4  334.
16068   2018    362 0     2.4    -1.3   8.3  530.
16069   2018    363 0     2.3    -0.3   3.6  535.
16070   2018    364 0     2.2    -0.4   4.5  539.
16071   2018    365 0     1.0    -0.2   4.5  483.
```

with dimension `116127 rows × 11 columns`
The code i have tried is

```
df1['new'] = df1['new'].astype(str)
df3['DOY'] = df3['DOY'].astype(str)
disturbed_day_list=pd.merge(df1, df3, left_on=['new'], right_on=['DOY'], how='left')
disturbed_day_list = disturbed_day_list.dropna()
disturbed_day_list
```

Getting the output as

```
       DDAY MM  YYYY_x  new YYYY_y  DOY HR    By      Bz    Nsw   Vsw
0       8   1   1975    8   1975    8   0    1.9    -0.2    5.6   695.
1       8   1   1975    8   1976    8   0   -5.0    -0.2    5.2   395.
2       8   1   1975    8   1977    8   0    0.4     1.5    8.1   413.
3       8   1   1975    8   1978    8   0    0.2     1.2   15.0   467.
4       8   1   1975    8   1979    8   0   -4.6     4.1    5.3   447.
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
116122  7   12  2018    341 2014    341 0   -1.9    -0.7    3.1   718.
116123  7   12  2018    341 2015    341 0    4.1     0.4    4.2   590.
116124  7   12  2018    341 2016    341 0    1.0     0.2   14.4   341.
116125  7   12  2018    341 2017    341 0    1.1    -0.4    3.4   501.
116126  7   12  2018    341 2018    341 0   -2.4    -0.8    9.1   444.
```

Having dimension `116127 rows × 11 columns`, but it should be of `2640 rows × 4 columns`.
Please help me out.

Comment: Try `df1.merge(df3, left_on=['new'], right_on=['DOY'], how='left')`

Comment: have you check if you have many to one relationship of df2 to df1? if you do, that will increase the number of rows above 2640.

have a look in the documentation example for merging too. you might be doing tit wrong https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: @snag9677 it is giving the similar output as in my question

Comment: @TOlaleye can you please come up with a code

Comment: It is a one to one relationship

Comment: Please provide some source data (in text form), of smaller size. Include also the result and show what is exactly wrong in it. Another hint: If you want only **4** columns in the output, specify which columns you want.